# How do I make a type anywhere text area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to all of this. I want a user to be able to type anywhere in a text area. Wherever the cursor is when they click is where they start typing. Is this something that can be done in a textarea or is there a better way to make this happen in HTML?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you mean something like [MS Office Word's _click-and-type_ feature](https://chrismenardtraining.com/post/click-and-type-anywhere-in-microsoft-word)?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant and also I didn't know that was something you could do

Comment: How do you add that feature in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a way to fill your **textarea** with spaces and then you can type wherever you clicked on.

use JQuery :

```
var $contentTextarea = $("textarea[name='contents']");

var cols = Number($contentTextarea.attr("cols"));
var rows = Number($contentTextarea.attr("rows"));

for(var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++ ){
         $contentTextarea.append(" ");
    }
    $contentTextarea.append("\n");
}
```

check out this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/bkdvL9bk/) for more.

Comment: I'd upvote this answer, but you really don't need to use any jQuery for this.